# Gcloud app deploy error - Required Alpha Access for computer API Forbidden

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm new to Google App Engine and I'm getting a really odd error out of the deployment of my Django App that appears to be related to a lack of permissions for Alpha Access. The error says:

```
Updating service [default]...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Deployment Manager operation failed, name: operation-1480541820504-5428b814947c1-dfa6ed37-d2b5ecf3, error: [{"code":"RESOURCE_ERROR","location":"/deployments/aef-default-20161130t213509/resources/aef-default-20161130t213509-00","message":"Unexpected response from resource of type compute.alpha.regionInstanceGroupManager: 403 {\"code\":403,\"errors\":[{\"domain\":\"global\",\"message\":\"Required 'Alpha Access' permission for 'Compute API'\",\"reason\":\"forbidden\"}],\"message\":\"Required 'Alpha Access' permission for 'Compute API'\",\"statusMessage\":\"Forbidden\",\"requestPath\":\"https://www.googleapis.com/compute/alpha/projects/elumin-dev-us/regions/us-central1/instanceGroupManagers\"}"}
```

Can anyone shed any light? I've tried two different projects and get exactly the same error. The upload results in a running app version which throws a 500 server error when visited.

As far as I'm aware there isn't anything special about the app at all. It's not trying to access any resources other than itself. It works fine run on the local host, even hooked up to the cloud database instance. My app.yaml file is as follows:

```
# [START runtime]
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT elumin.wsgi

runtime_config:
python_version: 3
# [END runtime]
```

Comment: check that `python_version: 3` is actually indented relative to `runtime_config:` - just a shot in the dark. Also check that you have billing enabled on your project (required for GAE flex). Your app seems to be needing some alpha feature for some reason (maybe accidental), for which whitelisting is required: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/hdcuQqdPHXo

Answer (score 1):

This is related to attempting to use "env: flex". [This is now beta](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading), so this shouldn't be occurring any longer.